# How to add rewind buttons to lock screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avplayer, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have realized representation of my `AVPlayer` on iPhone lock screen via `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`. But I can't found how to add ±15 seconds rewind buttons like in standard Music app.
So the question is How to add this buttons on lock screen?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `AVAudioPlayer` at the moment, but the remote controlling method which is `- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event` must not be involved with the type of the player you're using.

Follow this:

In your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method add the following code:

```
//Make sure the system follows our playback status - to support the playback when the app enters the background mode.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Then add these methods:
`viewDidAppear:`: (if not implemented already)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //Once the view has loaded then we can register to begin recieving controls and we can become the first responder
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

`viewWillDisappear:` (if not implemented already)

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //End recieving events
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And:

```
//Make sure we can recieve remote control events
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //if it is a remote control event handle it correctly
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl)
    {
        if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay)
        {
            [self playAudio];
        }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause)
        {
            [self pauseAudio];
        }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause)
        {
            [self togglePlayPause];
        }

        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingBackward)
        {
            [self rewindTheAudio]; //You must implement 15" rewinding in this method.
        }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingForward)
        {
            [self fastForwardTheAudio]; //You must implement 15" fast-forwarding in this method.
        }

    }
}
```

This is working fine in my app, however if you want to be able to receive remote control events in all view controllers, then you should set it in the `AppDelegate`.